# adding UIView into subView of cell, UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

Im adding 2 texts into a cell of a table. What I am doing is

> UITableViewCell *cell =nil;
>
> NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
>
> cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
>
> if (cell == nil) {
>
> cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
>   initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
>   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
>
> [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80.0, 0.0, 220.0, 10.0)];
>
> mainLabel.tag       =   1003;
>
> mainLabel.text      =   @"Text 1";
>
> mainLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
>
> mainLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|
>   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
>     [cell.contentView addSubview:mainLabel];
>
> }

I do the same thing to add secondLabel to a cell.
What is displaying on the simulator is
[image]

Now the problem is the background of 2 UILabel is not the same with the background of the cell ( my cells are grouped in the table view )

Does anyone know how to fix this problem.

Any comments are welcomed here
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understand well the question, you need to **delete** the `UILabel` background because  you want to show the `UITableViewCell` background instead. So I think you only have to do that:

```
 mainLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the answer above, you should set the same color for both of the view.

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

or you can set the color of the View you set.